# Override Devise password invalid method

Tags: devise

I'm using Devise and the related Devise Security Extension gem, and am having trouble finding out how to override the standard password invalid message. I'm using config.password_regex to set the formatting requirements and using :secure_validatable in my related model, but the message I'm receiving when the user types an incorrect password is "Password is invalid." I've searched my entire codebase and am unable to find this message - I don't know how to override this message, and if there's a related locale file I should use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an i18n translation, like

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              invalid: Security requirements not fulfilled
```